# What do the Visual Studio watch window icons represent?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

What do the each of the watch window icons and overlays in Visual Studio represent?  Is there a legend on an MSDN page somewhere?

[image: Example of some icons]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The icons identify the kind of the entity being watched; the same icons are also used in IntelliSense, Class View, and the Object Browser (and in Visual Studio 2012, the enhanced Solution Explorer).

There's an overview of the icons on MSDN:  [Class View and Object Browser Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.100)) (the [icons in Visual Studio 2012 are similar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.110)), but styled different).

**Added**

If you google for class and object browser icons then you should see the latest e.g. this one for VS 2019  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2019

Some shown in this image from that page

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For VS2013 here's the icon reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Reference for **Visual Studio 2022**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons